# How do I find Jenkinsfile properties?

Tags: jenkins

How does one go about finding the documentation on Jenkinsfile configuration options provided by Jenkins and the plugins that are installed?

For example, to set the "Do not allow concurrent builds" option, I have to set `properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])`. I don't see documentation on that option anywhere except under the documentation on declarative syntax.

For plugins, I have the Github plugin installed but I don't know how to find what the option is to check "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling". I don't see documentation on the plugin page or github page.

Do I need to dig into the source to find these options? If so, what am I looking for in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it under the Pipeline Syntax generator. There's a sample step for properties that allows you to check all the boxes and will generate the relevant code for you.